# Javascript code works in Safari, but not Firefox. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, safari

This script produces the expected results in Safari, but not Firefox. (These are the only two browsers I've tested it with.)

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<form name="inputForm">

    Weight:<input type="number" name="weight"> (lbs) <br>
    Height:<input type="number" name="height"> (inches) <br>
    <hr>
    <input type="button" name="process" value="Calculate" onclick="calcBMI(weight.value, height.value)">
    <hr>
    BMI: <input type="text" readonly name="bmiResult">  

</form>
```

And here is the entire Javascript, which is placed in the `<head>...</head>` tags of the HTML:

```
<script>
    var BMIMULTI = 703;

    function calcBMI(weight, height)
    {
        var bmi = (weight * BMIMULTI) / (height * height);
        document.inputForm.bmiResult.value = bmi;
    }
</script>
```

The consoles in both browsers show no errors. I have no external files I am linking to for either CSS or JS.

From my own debugging, I've discovered the problem lies with the `height.value` in the `onclick="calcBMI(...)"`. The value for `height.value` is being passed in to the `calcBMI` function as `null`, whereas the `weight.value` is passed in appropriately.

In Safari, both values are passed into the `calcBMI` function successfully.

Why does this happen? And, why does it occur in Firefox and not Safari?
I'm new to javascript, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` element (which is the current scope within the event handler) also has a `height` property in some browsers, which will prevent you from accessing the field by that name from the outer scope.

Get the fields as members of the form instead of using the global scope:

```
calcBMI(this.form.weight.value, this.form.height.value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to prevent using common word like height as your variable.
I have experienced similar problem before. I used "remove" as function name which works fine in the past but failed after firefox update.